# How to use keys from Solana keygen to use a web wallet?

Tags: phantomjs, solana

I ran this CLI command

```
solana-keygen new --outfile ~/my-solana-wallet/my-keypair.json
```

And have copied down the public key, BIP39 passphrase and 12 seed words. When I copy the seed words into phantom and sollet it shows empty accounts. I sent SOL to that public key address and worried I have lost it.

How do I access my account through sollet or phatom wallets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy the contents of `my-keypair.json` and hit import wallet in phantom and paste this private key there. Then your account should be showing up.

Also check on which net you're on. Could be devnet/ testnet/ or localnet.
The balances in each network would be different.

For getting SOL token on devnet you can use the airdrop function from the [cli](https://docs.solana.com/cli/transfer-tokens#:%7E:text=Airdrop%20some%20tokens%20to%20get%20started%23)

Comment: do you know how to do the opposite? import a phantom wallet private key into solana CLI?

Comment: export the key and store it in a json file?

Comment: No use , these are numbers in json file so you need to convert them...No import is done in phantom..!! Phantom is asking for a security key of the wallet, not just numbers..!!

Answer (score 0):

The first command you should run is:

`solana-keygen recover --force 'prompt:?key=0/0' --outfile ~/.config/solana/id.json`

Then the system will ask you to send the words. To do that, run a command like this:

`solana transfer --from ~/.config/solana/id.json asjfdklasjdfklasjdfaksjdlkdkdkdjfdkjk 60.75 --fee-payer ~/.config/solana/id.json`